# BackboneJS with normal php server

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backboneJS so i have a problem sync the data from PHP server with backbone that i dont even get the json data from the php server to backbone model!Help me 
Here is my php code

```
$data = array('1'=>array('id'=> 1, 'description'=>'Pick up milk', 'status'=> 'incomplete' ));
echo json_encode($data);
```

and the backbone js code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});
         var todoItem = new TodoItem();
         todoItem.url = '/backboneJS/todo.php';
         console.log(todoItem.fetch());
    </script>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I cant get the json data from the php to the backbone.What wrong with my code ?

Comment: Please tell us the error in the inspector if any.

Comment: If the actual XHR call going to the todo.php, what's response if it is? Use your browser developer debug tool, filter xhr in network calls. Alternatively use fiddler2, which may be bit overhwelming for this task.

Comment: i did it on my localhost of course!
it does send a get request from the client

GET http://localhost/backboneJS/todo.php
 return : {"1":{"id":1,"description":"Pick up milk","status":"incomplete"}}

Comment: the error is this line of code
    console.log(todoItem.fetch()); doesnt return my json from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/backboneJS/todo.php',
        initialize: function(){
            // Place init message or else
        }
    });

    var todoItem = new TodoModel();

    todoItem.fetch({
        success: function(todoResult){
            console.log(todoResult);
            console.log(todoItem.get(1));
        }
    });


</script>
</html>
```

Sticking to design pattern also, if you call your todoItem outside of nested function its likely to be executed before the actual fetch() is performed. Tested locally.